# Создание нейросетей, машинное обучение

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Появилось желание попробовать себя в создании нейросетей, машинном обучении. Хочу узнать:

1. С чего лучше начать изучение.
2. Какие среды разработки и библиотеки лучше использовать.
3. Какой язык выбрать (пишу на java и c#).
4. Какую литературу прочитать.
5. Возможные трудности

Надеюсь на конструктивные ответы. Кто имел опыт работы с машинным обучением также прошу поделиться опытом.

Comment: начни с пролога

Comment: Переходите на python, R или matlab. Для питона есть отличная библиотека, keras. Кроме того, Вам не стоит путать термины машинное обучение -- это область, которая агрегирует в себе несколько понятий: оптимизация функций, численные методы решения уравнений, теория моделей (как построить модель), статистические методы. Нейронные сети -- это метод, конкретный метод, который может отличаться реализацией при решении разного класса задач. При этом метод НС, как правило, позволяет легко перейти от одного метода к другим.